# Create and instance of a model for each user currently in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using Mongoid for the database in my Rails app. I've had this User model for a little while and now I just created a new Preference model where a User has_one preference and a Preference belongs_to a user. How do I create an instance of Preference for each of the existing users in my database?

SOLUTION:

I simply went to the Rails console and ran the following:

```
for user in User
    unless Preference.find_by(user_id: user.id)
        p = Preference.new(id: user.id, user_id: user_id)
        p.save
    end
end
```

Never imagined it could be this easy :)

Answer (score 1):

It will create for you `Preference` for each created user and id of user will be the same with preference !

In **User.rb**

```
before_create :set_preference

def set_preference
    build_preference(id: self.id, user_id: self.id, email: self.email)
end
```

Comment: But how about the users already in my database? This seems like it will only work for future users.